# Django Channels - receiver function called multiple times depending on number of open web sockets

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I don't understand the behavior of Django Channels 2.4.0. When multiple web sockets are open, the receiver function is called as often as web sockets are open.

Here the minimal code from the well-known chat example of the channels documentation

```
    # Receive message from WebSocket
async def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']

    # Send message to room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'message': message
        }
    )

# Receive message from room group
async def chat_message(self, event):
    print(event) # this is called as often as sockets are open
    message = event['message']
    # Send message to WebSocket
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'message': message
    }))
```

The problem becomes strong when I want to do logic things in the database triggered from the receiver function. Then things start to be done multiple times depending how many web sockets are open. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: It is not understandable to me!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django channels creates one instance of your Consumer class per open websocket connection.

The idea of the `group_send` is to call that function that corresponds to your `type` value. This function is called on every consumer instance that has subscribed (`group_add`) to that group.

If you have work to do that is not dependent individual connections (eg user id might be different per connection) then do it before you `group_send` message.

So if you need to query your db do that before your `group_send` then serialize the results and send them over the channel layer as part of your `group_send` message.

However if your DB query needs to consider the subscribed user (aka filter out info that they are not permitted to see) then you need to do this in the `chat_message` handler and it will be called for every subscribed connection. Alternatively you can do a query before `group_send` that exposes the needed information so that in your `chat_message` you can just inspect the message to determine if it can be sent to the user.